# Append empty string to last value in list in for-loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web-scrape a webpage and while doing so I'm looking to extract specific information like the location name, latitude, longitude and film name. However, when extracting this information across multiple web-pages I'm unsure to which film the three previous values belong to.

I had thought of a way to overcome this by creating an empty string after all the values of the first three for each film, where I can then split these into lists per film when it reaches an empty string.

Though, I'm having difficulties trying to get the empty string right, here's what I have done:

```
test = ['https://www.latlong.net/location/10-things-i-hate-about-you-locations-250',
 'https://www.latlong.net/location/12-angry-men-locations-818',
 'https://www.latlong.net/location/12-monkeys-locations-501']

for i in range(0, len(test), 1):
    r = requests.get(test[i])
    testone = {'location name':[],'film':[]}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    for th in soup.select("td"):
        testone['location name'].append(th.text.strip())
        testone['location name'].append('')
    for h in soup.select_one("h3"):
        testone['film'].append(h)
```

However this seems to append an empty string after each value:

```
'location name': ["1117 Broadway (Gil's Music Shop)",
  '',
  '47.252495',
  '',
  '-122.439644',
  '',
  "2715 North Junett St (Kat and Bianca's House)",
  '',
  '47.272591',
  '',
  '-122.474480', ....
```

My expectation:

```
'location name': ["1117 Broadway (Gil's Music Shop)",
  '47.252495',
  '-122.439644',
  "2715 North Junett St (Kat and Bianca's House)",
  '47.272591',
  '-122.474480',
  'Aurora Bridge',
  '47.646713',
  '-122.347435',
  'Buckaroo Tavern (closed)',
  '47.657841',
  '-122.350327',
  'Century Ballroom',
  '47.615028',
  '-122.319855',
  'Fremont Place Books (closed)',
  '47.650452',
  '-122.350510',
  'Fremont Troll',
  '47.651093',
  '-122.347435',
  'Gas Works Park',
  '47.645561',
  '-122.334496',
  'Kerry Park',
  '47.629402',
  '-122.360008',
  'Kingdome',
  '47.595993',
  '-122.333649',
  'Paramount Theatre',
  '47.613235',
  '-122.331451',
  'Seattle',
  '47.601871',
  '-122.341248',
  'Stadium High School',
  '47.265991',
  '-122.448570',
  'Tacoma',
  '47.250828',
  '-122.449135',
  '',
  'New York City',
  '40.742298',
  '-73.982559',
  'New York County Courthouse',
  '40.714310',
  '-74.001930',
  '', ................],
 'film': ['10 Things I Hate About You Locations Map','12 Angry Men Locations Map'...]}
```

Comment: `testone['location name'].append('')` - what do you think this line  does?

Answer (score -1):

Use `extned()` instead of `append()`; since the `strip()` function returns a `list` ,and you want to append all items of the list to `testone['location name']`
Try this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(test), 1):
    r = requests.get(test[i])
    testone = {'location name':[],'film':[]}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    for th in soup.select("td"):
        testone['location name'].extend(th.text.strip())
        # Do nothing
    for h in soup.select_one("h3"):
        testone['film'].append(h)
```

Comment: This is not my preferred result as I need to know which films belong to which locations, latitude and longitude. I have a script already saved that can split the three into lists relative to the film but I require an empty string.

Comment: Will you please give a sample of your expectations?

Comment: Look at the question, it's already uploaded ...

Comment: Your expectation which you've mentioned in the question is what my code will output.

Comment: look carefully ...

Comment: This seems to be worse than before. I get an empty line string after every letter/number

Comment: It doesn't seem to do as what you say ... @Stackcans Would you like to have a meeting on google meet, to see the problem?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to

Comment: HI @Stackcans, How did you do with your problem? Do you still need help?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're appending an empty string `''` after each table
cell you read. In this way, since you have 3 separate cell for location name, longitude and latitude, you are inserting an empty string between each one.

An optimal solution could be to add a counter and store everything inside a map instead of two lists:

```
test = ['https://www.latlong.net/location/10-things-i-hate-about-you-locations-250',
'https://www.latlong.net/location/12-angry-men-locations-818',
'https://www.latlong.net/location/12-monkeys-locations-501']

for i in range(0, len(test), 1):
   r = requests.get(test[i])
   testone = {}
   cells = soup.select("td")
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
   for h in soup.select_one("h3"):
       testone[h] = list()
       for j in range(3):
           testone[h].append(cells.pop(0))
```

In this way you can have all the information about a film by using `testone[<filmname>]`

Comment: This almost seems to work but why do you have another for loop indexing `i` in the end, when it's already been done at the beginning? Furthermore, when you ```cell.pop(0)``` it only selects one value which is not stripped of its tag. Have you tested this out?

Comment: You have many errors in your code which I got working with: ```testone = {}
for i in range(0, len(test), 1):
   r = requests.get(test[i])
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
   cells = soup.select("td")
   for h in soup.select_one("h3"):
       testone[h] = []
       for j in cells:
           testone[h].append(j.text.strip())``` However, it does not answer my question on including an empty string, so I cannot award a tick. The structure of the dictionary does not allow a pandas dataframe. Whereas my approach with an empty string included would if it can be managed

Comment: @Stackcans you are right about changing the index of the third loop to `j`, but you still need to iterate over `'range(3)` and not over `cells`. In this way you will have several separated lists and no need for an empty string

Comment: Where in your code is the index `j` actually being used? Don't you mean to use it for it to iterate over ```range(3)```?. It still fails to do what you say - have you checked that it works that way that you mention?

Comment: It is simply used to pop 3 items from the cells list: One for the name, one for the latitude and the final for longitude